# ApostropheCMS error during editor modal save when joining a piece to a module

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I created a new "modal" piece where I'm joining another module (so I can display modules inside the modal). I can select the module in the editor modal, but when I save I get this error pop up: `An error occurred. Please try again later.` Front-end console shows this is coming from `/modules/apostrophe-browser-utils/js/always.js`

All I have is the **/lib/modules/modal/index.js** file like this:

```
module.exports = {
    extend: "apostrophe-pieces",
    name: "modal",
    label: "Modal",
    seo: false,
    addFields: [
      {
        name: "_image",
        type: "joinByOne",
        withType: "apostrophe-image",
        label: "Pick an image",
        required: true,
        idField: "_id",
        filters: {
          // Thought maybe not having a projection was an issue. didn't help
          projection: {
            attachment: 1
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  };
```

Screen Cap: https://screencast.com/t/OGQOD0PiG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `idField` name is conflicting with the default id property all apostrophe docs have. Change it to something like `imageId`. In all cases EXCEPT `_id`, the `_` prefix in apostrophe indicates a property that is 'filled in' by apostrophe at some point, and not actually saved with the doc.